# Numpy computes eigenvalues wrongly. What to do?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I use `evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(matrix)` to find the eigenvalues in my square matrix, which is a Laplacian of a connected graph, therefore one of the eigenvalues should equal to 0. According to numpy, none does.
Seeing posts in the web proposing using SymPy, I did it, but SymPy says it can't compute the eigenvalues as well...
As I only need to look at the smallest non-zero eigevalue's vector, is there a way to get it without maybe computing all of the eigenvalues? Or am I missing something?

The matrix:

```
[[49.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 46.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 42.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 40.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 49.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 33.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 34.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 26.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 35.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 27.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 39.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 38.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 26.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 37.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 42.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 53.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 41.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 40.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 38.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 39.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 41.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0], [0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0], [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 22.0]]
```

Comment: Posting your matrix as an image file might be a better way to go. What is the smallest eigenvalue you get out of numpy? You might expect some numerical error.

Comment: The smallest one is -2.10346185e-14. Should I try to round it maybe? How many decimal places are relevant?

Answer (score 1):

One of the values in `evals` is really close to Zero

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

mat = np.array([[ ... ]])
evals, evecs = la.eig(mat)

print(min(evals))
```

output:

```
-2.103461851787978e-14+0j
```

Maybe just a rounding problem?

**Edit**: You can set the smallest value to Zero:

```
evals[evals==min(evals)] = 0
```

Comment: Yeah, just figured this commenting above. But where to draw a line? I mean I'm supposed to calculate this for a number of 64x64 matrices. Should I expect each of them having their non-zero eigenvalues to be above, say: 1/10000?

Comment: @Warxuaroz you may use the machine epsilon e.g. `evals[np.abs(evals) < np.finfo(float).eps] = 0` where `np.finfo(float).eps)` is 2.22044604925e-16, or similarly `np.finfo(np.float32).eps` which is 1.19209e-07

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer from drops is the best for your case but I thought I'd fill in on how to do this with sympy (as much as it can be done).

I guess that SymPy's eigenvals method fails because it attempts to get analytic expressions for all roots or it doesn't try hard enough to compute them numerically.

You can compute the characteristic polynomial exactly using sympy:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: M = Matrix(mat).applyfunc(nsimplify)  # use Rational not Float

In [3]: p = M.charpoly()

In [5]: roots(p)
Out[5]: {0: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 22: 1}
```

That's not all the roots because I think some cannot be expressed analytically due to Abel-Ruffini. It shows you have one eigenvalue that is exactly zero though.

You can calculate all distinct roots numerically to a precision of 15 digits with:

```
In [8]: p.nroots(maxsteps=200)
Out[8]: 
[0, 3.64229738164612, 3.90809447390274, 5.52592388083055, 7.0, 7.0, 7.47573322071306, 7.93969470479046, 7.96451740909676, 8.0, 8.122275776619
34, 8.81468070255738, 8.8414791318685, 9.74504220850479, 10.0096086916188, 13.5758426960366, 13.831550041897, 14.9871090273419, 15.9280653213
398, 17.6934130265373, 17.8492471846067, 18.4023642549967, 19.8527304371997, 20.0960198685171, 20.3618336767453, 20.553641086389, 20.77145325
41294, 21.2502694880938, 21.6133998195161, 21.9236222999373, 22.0, 23.1448434582352, 23.2014152187474, 24.0030852296899, 24.4976521431209, 26
.2349104244148, 26.9701014334474, 27.0857540335953, 27.5331684833294, 28.2205682443131, 28.8149041382197, 29.9067921711097, 33.1682630698899,
 34.6597983161431, 35.4062778394657, 35.8447160110416, 36.1771054883514, 37.5408587655317, 37.7755441264447, 38.6227160277802, 38.81217004335
9, 39.1686183173795, 39.4632679789674, 40.1892768140105, 41.1240249697988, 41.6504372854375, 42.1806931278361, 42.5997600719663, 43.622924681
5524, 44.1592126182527, 47.0710985678097, 49.8945154195281, 50.4337489603871, 54.1418674554114]
```

Although this gives the zero eigenvalue exactly, the smallest nonzero eigenvalue can only be found numerically. We can still work with that but need to go back to using numpy/scipy numerically at that point (sympy's `nullspace` isn't so good with floating point):

```
In [60]: sev = _[1]                                                                                                                            

In [61]: Mnp = np.array(M - sev*eye(64), float)                                                                                                

In [62]: from scipy.linalg import null_space                                                                                                   

In [63]: null_space(Mnp)                                                                                                                       
Out[63]: 
array([[ 0.01631163],
       [-0.00923361],
       [-0.01541704],
       [-0.01530411],
       [-0.00961362],
       [-0.00738385],
       [-0.00962764],
       [-0.02145502],
       [-0.00977645],
       [-0.01019995],
       [-0.04299075],
       [-0.00718198],
       [-0.04672266],
       [-0.00641006],
       [-0.00691489],
       [ 0.05603999],
       [-0.00826585],
       [-0.04107796],
       [-0.00102892],
       [-0.00853086],
       [-0.0410991 ],
       [-0.01818659],
       [-0.04364203],
       [-0.00916758],
       [-0.01318757],
       [ 0.02320424],
       [-0.02171701],
       [ 0.24047418],
       [-0.0080679 ],
       [-0.00102074],
       [-0.00876802],
       [-0.00370487],
       [-0.00728112],
       [-0.01221379],
       [-0.00803625],
       [-0.06287915],
       [-0.04574548],
       [ 0.93941174],
       [-0.04581733],
       [-0.0081365 ],
       [-0.00451854],
       [-0.01836332],
       [-0.01002025],
       [-0.00834197],
       [-0.00491533],
       [-0.07704808],
       [-0.07704808],
       [-0.04264412],
       [-0.01623985],
       [-0.00423235],
       [-0.07704808],
       [-0.01897522],
       [-0.0615733 ],
       [-0.00832049],
       [-0.0149924 ],
       [-0.00897482],
       [-0.00451989],
       [-0.00823121],
       [-0.06354062],
       [-0.02840004],
       [-0.01836332],
       [ 0.01870191],
       [-0.06354062],
       [-0.01848555]])
```

Using symbolic calculation like this is slow but if you're struggling with numerical problems it might help...